# PHP/MySql user registration, how can i make a user that wants to register not use the same username?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm making a web page, and I want the users to have a username and a password, but I don't want the usernames to repeated, My database is already connected to my web page and a section for them to put their information, such as name, username, password, etc.

I need help on how to warn the user to input another username if the one they have entered is already taken. Here's my code in HTML/PHP/MySQL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Skillfair</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesbd_o.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section id="header" class="jumbotron">
  <header class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="col-sm-4">Database</h2>
      <nav class="col-sm-8 text-right">
          <p id="btnregister">Register</p>
          <!--antes estaba escrito newest en vez de register-->
        <p id="btncatalogo">Catalogue</p>
        <p id="btnlogin">Login</p>
          <!--antes estaba escrito contact en vez de login-->
          <p id="btncart">Cart</p>
      </nav> 
    </div>
  </header>
  </section>

     <!--Seccion de la parte del registro -->
    <section id="registro1"  class="container">
    <div id="registro">
    <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-sm-12">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return valido()">
            <fieldset class="col-sm-12">
           <h1>Register <span> now!</span></h1>
            <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="You must input your username" maxlength="20">    
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="You must input your password" maxlength="20">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="You must input your name(s)" maxlength="20">                
            <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="You must input your lastname" maxlength="20">
            <input name="school" type="text" placeholder="You must input your school" maxlength="20">
            <input name="age" type="number" placeholder="You must input your age" maxlength="2">
            <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="You must input your phone number" maxlength="20">
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="You must input your email" maxlength="35">
            <button type="submit">Sent Data</button>
            <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Clear fields" id="reset">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <p id="sent">
        </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>

    <!--Seccion de la parte del catalogo -->
  <section  class="container">
    <div id="catalogo">
    <div class="row">
       <figure class="col-sm-6">
         <p>-kitchen</p>
         <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/kitchen.jpg"/>
       </figure>
       <figure class="col-sm-6">
         <p>-woodwork</p>
         <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/woodwork.jpg"/>
       </figure>     
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <figure class="col-sm-6">
         <p>-gifts</p>
         <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/gifts.jpg"/>
       </figure>
       <figure class="col-sm-6">
         <p>-antiques</p>
         <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/antique.jpg"/>
       </figure>      
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="container">
    <div class ="row">
      <p class="col-sm-4">&copy; 2016 Skillfair</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

    <!-- Faltan registros (javascript)-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function valido () {
                if(document.form1.username.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your username');
                    document.form1.username.focus();
                    return false;
                }   
                if(document.form1.password.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your password');
                    document.form1.password.focus();
                    return false;
                }   
                if(document.form1.name.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your name');
                    document.form1.name.focus();
                    return false;
                }   
                if(document.form1.lastname.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your last name');
                    document.form1.lastname.focus();
                    return false;
                }   
                if(document.form1.school.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your school');
                    document.form1.school.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if(document.form1.age.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your age');
                    document.form1.age.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if(document.form1.phone.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your phone number');
                    document.form1.phone.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if(document.form1.email.value=="") {
                    alert ('You must input your email');
                    document.form1.email.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                    else {
                    alert ('Success!!');
                    return true;
                }
            }

            </script>

<script>
    /* script para la apertura y cierre del boton register */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnregister").click(function(){
       $("#registro").fadeToggle("slow");
       $("#catalogo").hide();
    });
    $("#registro").hide();

});
    /* script para la apertura y cierre del boton catalogo */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btncatalogo").click(function(){
       $("#catalogo").fadeToggle("slow");
       $("#registro").hide();
    });
    $("#catalogo").hide();

});

</script>

    <?php
    //Connect to database
    mysql_pconnect('localhost:8889','xxxx','xxxx');
    //***********************
    //Select database
    mysql_select_db('users');
    //***********************
    //Insert data into database
    if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {
    $username=$_POST['username'];    
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $school=$_POST['school'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $cad="insert into users.data (username, password, name, lastname, school, age, phone, email) values ('".$username."','".$password."','".$name."','".$lastname."','".$school."','".$age."','".$phone."','".$email."') ";
    mysql_query($cad);
    }
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry if the comments and some other things are in spanish because my code was originally in spanish but i tried to translate it as much as i could, so please, if anybody could help me with this issue that would be great!!

Comment: Make an ajax call to a php files which checks the username and return the response into a div in the main page.If answer is negative alow to form to submit

Comment: please delete this post and make a new one. Don't add any sensibility data!

Comment: Make `username` unique, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html; or check that the username isn't there before doing the insert. This is open to SQL injections. Passwords shouldnt  be plain text.

Comment: You are using deprecated and insecure stuff, please review [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) as well.

Comment: If you use surrogate key for your primary index, you unique constraint on the username field. And if you want case insensitive unique username, use a case insensitive collation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality using ajax. Just post data to the php file which checks for duplication using ajax.

Here is an example which should solve your problem.

**HTML**

`<input type="text" id="user" name="user" disabled="true" required><br><span id="usererr"></span>`

**jquery code**

```
$("#user").keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'user=' + user;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'checkusername.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html)
        {

            $("#usererr").html(html);

        }
    });
 });
```

**PHP (CODE checkuser.php)**

```
if($_POST)
{
 if(isset($_POST['user']))
 {
    $user= strtolower(sanitizeString($_POST['user']));

    $query="select * from users.data where username='".$user."'";
    $result=  mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        echo '<font color="green">Username is Available</font><br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<font color="red">Username is already taken. Please select another username.</font><br>';
        echo '<script language="javascript">var user=document.getElementById("user");'
        . 'user.value="";</script>';
    }

 }
}
```

**NOTE: mysql_* functions are depreciated and no longer used. I have provided the code as per your need. It is highly recommended that you upgrade to mysqli_* functions.**

Comment: With double quotes, you can simply do $query="select * from users.data where username='$user'";